# How can I tell if a fish bone is stuck in my throat?

Tags: fish, choking, swallow-swallowing, throat, foreign-body-object

So I had fish for dinner. I felt a sharp pain in my mouth, but don't know why but decided to swallow it instead of spitting it out. Now I don't know if it stuck in my throat or did it went down. Now I keep feeling there is something stuck in my throat. I'm in no pain even when I'm swallowing.

Comment: It may actually just be that the bone scratched your throat which is now causing the disconfort

Comment: Personal medical advice has to be given by a physician in person, so the site rules prohibit us from providing any here.

Answer (score 1):

It's often difficult to tell the difference between an esophageal abrasion and a foreign body just by how you feel.  If you get it checked out and it's just an abrasion, no biggie; if you don't and it's a foreign body, it could result in infection or perforation.

From [an EM website](http://www.ncemi.org/cse/cse0313.htm):

> All patients who complain of a foreign body of the throat should be taken seriously. Even relatively smooth or rounded objects that remain impacted in the esophagus have the potential for serious problems, and a fish bone can perforate the esophagus in only a few days.

Comment: So basically, we know if it's a foreign body as soon as we have an infection or perforation?

Comment: That's a possibility, yes.  My point is that it's not something to blow off.  It's usually just an abrasion that you just keep feeling, but as the EM website explains, take it seriously so if the body is actually there it doesn't lead to perf or infection. In the ER the doc can get a good history, exam, XRay, and even scope the esophagus or other testing.  On your own it's hard to tell.  Then if it's not just an abrasion, they can do something about it. If it's an abrasion, at least you've got the reassurance of knowing.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on its size, it hurts, it makes you cough, and swallowing food will worsen symptoms. The tendency is for symptoms to get worse if that foreign body isn't removed or carried down to the stomach.  If you don't seek medical attention, bacteria may invade the sub-mucosae and infect the area. Therefore, if you feel you've swallowed something that got stuck in your throat or oesophagus, look for an E.R. immediately.